# Case statement with join clause

Tags: sql, expression, case

I have a table A as below

```
Acct_nbr      acount_relation_nbr     acct_relation_code     property
1             0                       0                      12345
1             9                       T                      ----
2             0                       0                      345
2             9                       0                      ----
```

The acct number can have more than a primary and secondary record which is differentiated through account_relation_nbr column - if 0 then primary , if 9 then secondary. 
I want to be able to write a case expression in SQl based on below condition - if acount _relation_nbr =9, then it picks the property_id from acount_relation_nbr =0, since they are 2 records for a same acount number.
Bsed on outcome for property_id, This will populate property_id column in another table B. 
Hope I have made my question clear. Any inputs will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Pallavi

Comment: Please edit your question and show the results that you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could precalculate your property value for `acount_relation_nbr = 0` and then use a `case` to use that value when  `acount_relation_nbr = 9`

```
 SELECT Acct_nbr
    ,acount_relation_nbr
    ,acct_relation_code
    ,CASE 
        WHEN acount_relation_nbr = 9
            THEN cte.property
        ELSE tableA.property
        END property
FROM TABLEA
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT property
        ,Acct_nbr
    FROM tableA
    WHERE acount_relation_nbr = 0
    ) CTE 
ON TABLEA.Acct_nbr = CTE.Acct_nbr
```

Comment: I am anew user in this forum. How do I acept something as an answer. Is there any option for me to do so.

Answer (score 0):

So I assume that you're trying to get output like this:

```
Acct_nbr      acount_relation_nbr     acct_relation_code     property
1             0                       0                      12345
1             9                       T                      12345
2             0                       0                      345
2             9                       0                      345
```

You can achieve this by using nested query, so you don't need case:

```
SELECT acct_nbr,account_relation_nbr,acct_relation_code,
   (SELECT property FROM TABLE inr 
   WHERE inr.acct_nbr = out.acct_nbr
         AND inr.account_relation_nbr=0) 
FROM TABLE out
```